# How can one sed the output of a variable above a certain line?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to modify a file above the line containing this string: 
[ moleculetype ]

The insert I am trying to do is saved in a variable like this one:

```
ATOMTYPES=$(sed -n '/^\[\ atomtypes\ \]/,/^\[\ moleculetype\ \]/p;/^\[\ moleculetype\ \]/q' LIG_GMX.top | sed '$d')
```

which contains the following text:

```
[ atomtypes ]
;name   bond_type     mass     charge   ptype   sigma         epsilon       Amb
 oh       oh          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.06647e-01   8.80314e-01 ; 1.72  0.2104
 nc       nc          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.25000e-01   7.11280e-01 ; 1.82  0.1700
 nd       nd          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.25000e-01   7.11280e-01 ; 1.82  0.1700
 na       na          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.25000e-01   7.11280e-01 ; 1.82  0.1700
 c3       c3          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.39967e-01   4.57730e-01 ; 1.91  0.1094
 ca       ca          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.39967e-01   3.59824e-01 ; 1.91  0.0860
 ho       ho          0.00000  0.00000   A     0.00000e+00   0.00000e+00 ; 0.00  0.0000
 h1       h1          0.00000  0.00000   A     2.47135e-01   6.56888e-02 ; 1.39  0.0157
 ha       ha          0.00000  0.00000   A     2.59964e-01   6.27600e-02 ; 1.46  0.0150
```

my desired output looks like this:

```
[ atomtypes ]
;name   bond_type     mass     charge   ptype   sigma         epsilon       Amb
 oh       oh          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.06647e-01   8.80314e-01 ; 1.72  0.2104
 nc       nc          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.25000e-01   7.11280e-01 ; 1.82  0.1700
 nd       nd          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.25000e-01   7.11280e-01 ; 1.82  0.1700
 na       na          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.25000e-01   7.11280e-01 ; 1.82  0.1700
 c3       c3          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.39967e-01   4.57730e-01 ; 1.91  0.1094
 ca       ca          0.00000  0.00000   A     3.39967e-01   3.59824e-01 ; 1.91  0.0860
 ho       ho          0.00000  0.00000   A     0.00000e+00   0.00000e+00 ; 0.00  0.0000
 h1       h1          0.00000  0.00000   A     2.47135e-01   6.56888e-02 ; 1.39  0.0157
 ha       ha          0.00000  0.00000   A     2.59964e-01   6.27600e-02 ; 1.46  0.0150

[ moleculetype ]
```

however when I use these commands:

```
sed "/^\[\ moleculetype\ \]/i | echo  $ATOMTYPES|" topol.top
```

or

```
sed "/^\[\ moleculetype\ \]/i  $ATOMTYPES" topol.top
```

The following error appears:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 50: extra characters after command
```

Comment: Maybe `echo  $ATOMTYPES |sed ...` ? You haven't clearly explained what do you want to achieve.

Comment: You want to *insert a sed command* into a file, using another sed command? I strongly suspect that what you're asking for is not what you want.

Comment: Please post example output matching sample input. Explaining with examples is really more clear then posting non-working commands. If you look at [man sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) you could see it's `i \<newline> text` and that is how it's supposed to work. Also, in sed commands end with newlines (Not with `;`. The `;` is parsed as another command in sed. The true command terminator is newline.), so if `$ATOMTYPES` is a multiline string, then `sed` is not the solution (or you need to substitute newlines with ex. `\n`, like `sed -z 's/\n/\\n/'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. sed is for doing s/old/new on individual strings, that is all. For anything more interesting you should be using awk. This is probably what you want (untested since you didn't provide sample input/output we could test against):

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    if ( /\[ atomtypes ]/ )    { f=1 }
    if ( /\[ moleculetype ]/ ) { f=0 }
    if ( f ) {
        atomtypes = atomtypes ors $0
        ors = ORS
    }
    next
}
/\[ moleculetype ]/ { print atomtypes }
{ print }
' LIG_GMX.top topol.top
```

If you're using GNU awk you can change `f=0` to `nextfile` for efficiency.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your help - I just updated the question. Is it clear enough now?

Comment: yes Ed, it worked. Many Thanks!